# Reading/extracting $date field value from JSON array

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file where each line is a JSON object (actually, it's a dump of stackoverflow). I was able to load this into Apache Pig easily, but I am having trouble in reading/extracting the "$date" from LastActivityDate. Could you please help me on how can I get the $date value from "LastActivityDate"?

Here is an example:

```
{ 
"_id" : { "$oid" : "506492073401d91fa7fdffbe" }, 
"Body" : "....", 
"ViewCount" : 7351, 
"LastEditorDisplayName" : "Rich B", 
"Title" : ".....", 
"LastEditorUserId" : 140328, 
"LastActivityDate" : { "$date" : 1314819738077 }, 
"LastEditDate" : { "$date" : 1313882544213 }, 
"AnswerCount" : 12, "CommentCount" : 19, 
"AcceptedAnswerId" : 7, 
"Score" : 83, 
"PostTypeId" : "question", 
"OwnerUserId" : 8, 
"Tags" : [ "c#", "winforms" ], 
"CreationDate" : { "$date" : 1217540572667 }, 
"FavoriteCount" : 13, "Id" : 4, 
"ForumName" : "stackoverflow.com" 
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
grunt> entitleGen1 = FOREACH entitleGen GENERATE id, ViewCount, LastActivityDate#'$date' as "LastActivityDate" :chararray;
2015-12-01 05:42:19,840 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Undefined parameter : date
```